# What are all the possible screen scales (ie ratio between real pixels and virtual pixels) of android devices

Tags: android, android-screen

I know 6 screen scales (the ratio between real pixels and virtual pixels) :

- 0.75x
- 1x
- 1.5x
- 2x
- 3x
- 4x

but is it possible to meet other screen scales on some devices ?

Comment: `dp/px` ratio can be any fraction you could imagine, what do you need it for?

Comment: but i would like to have a name of a device with other ratio to know that it's possible as i never never saw any (so maybe they not exists?). i need to know because in my software i want to make all my graphic in a way that opengl will not need to resize them. actually i need 5 pictures (but 0.75 not exist anymore)

Answer (score 0):

An OEM can make any ratio screen they want.  A dp is 160th of an inch.  So to find the ratio, take the pixel width of the device, take the physical width of the screen, find the number of pixels per inch, and divide by 160.  Almost no screen has an exact 2:1 ratio, for example (330 dpi was a common real dpi), those ratios are estimates.

Comment: thanks, but did you already see a device with ratio other that those i wrote ?

Comment: Yes.  For example, 330 dpi is actually 2.1.

Comment: hmm it's with device ? i think we don't speak the same think because i can't believe a device as a pixel ratio of 2.1

Comment: I think you're confused.  If you're talking about how many physical pixels is "1px" in android, the answer is always 1.  The idea of "virtual pixels" in android is "dp".  DP is actually a fixed physical size, 1 dp is 1/160th of an inch.  So it is quite possible to have a fractional ratio there, and in fact extremely common.

Comment: i don't know the name, but for example from a device, you go to https://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/ and it's will say you for example 320 * 640 but your phone have a screen of 640 * 1280 pixels so the ratio is 2

Comment: @noan That concept doesn't exist on Android.  1 px is always 1 physical pixel.  1 dp is always 1/160th of an inch.  Some framework on top of Android might decide to add that concept, but you need to specify what you're using.

Comment: bah no, it's exist because your webbrowser say you have 320 * 640 (and all your javascripts work on this resolution) when in fact you have 640 * 1280 pixels. this mean when in javascript you draw a line of 1 px height (virtual pixels), then on the screen it's will in fact use 2 pixels (real pixels). make a screen copy and you will see exactly this

Comment: Ok, so you're using some JS framework that uses a base resolution (which we don't know what it is) and gets a ratio off that.   The answer there is-  any ratio is possible.  There is no requirement for hardware manufacturers to create screens in any exact size, so the ratio could be anything-  including fractional.  Not to mention a given webview could not be full screen and thus give you an even weirder ratio.  In fact the odds that its a non-fractional number is extremely tiny.

Comment: but i would like to have a prove of it, as i never saw (never never) any other screen ratios than thoses i wrote. just one example of one device that not feet in theses numbers will be enough for me

Comment: I suggest you rewrite this question, tag it CSS and Javascript, and explain that you're asking for information on the css scaling.  As written, your question looked to be about the actual android OS scaling.  Its now clear you want to ask about javascript css scaling-  which is a totally different concept and needs a different pool of people looking at it.

Comment: in fact i don't use css nor javascript, it's was just to show you a sample in a quick and easy way :) i use opengl and Delphi actually :) and also java ... i maybe don't know the exact naming but it's what i call ratio between real pixels and virtual pixels

Comment: @noan And I'm trying to tell you that Android doesn't have the concept of virtual pixels.  At all.  You always work in physical pixels.  The closest thing it has is dp, which is basically working in inches.  And even that only is used in xml layout files, when making calls to View objects or canvas objects its always physical pixels.

Comment: i don't know, i work on android for more than 3 years (in java, delphi, opengl, html, javascript, etc.), and this concept is quite present. maybe you mean on Android Studio their is not such concept? but you have this concept it in the directory xxxdpi (mean 4x) xxdpi (mean 3x) xdpi (mean 2x) hdpi (mean 1.5x) and mdpi (mean 1x) of the res folders

Comment: THat's dp scaling, used only in layout files.  And those are estimates, the actual ratios are not exact numbers.  xxxdpi means about 4.0, but it can be higher or lower.  Its almost never exactly 4.0

Comment: exactly, and what i would like to know is if their is any (just a sample will be enalf) of a device with something else than 4.0 (like 4.2 or 3.8). else it's look like xxxdpi mean 4.0 as a norm

Comment: Almost every device is not exactly right.  But it would still be mapped to one of those buckets as a rough estimate.

Comment: hmm you have a doc about this mapping ?

Comment: How were you measuring they were exactly right?  There's a function that returns the multiple, but it doesn't return the real multiple-  it returns the multiple for the bucket its placed in.  TO determine the real multiple, you'd need to get the screen's physical size, the screen width in pixel, and do the math yourself.

Comment: Better source:  https://material.io/devices/     Notice the px/in on devices when you click on them.  They are not exact multiples of 160.  Google's Pixel XL is 534, which is a 3.35 ratio